# merging of text

Tags: c, windows, merge

Can you please help me with merging of two texts into one using just only `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`? The result should be `HelloWorld`.

So far, I have the following, but there is a mistake somewhere.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *spojeni(char *t1, char *t2)
{
    char pole_spolecne[10];
    for (*t1 = 0; *t1 < 5; t1++)
    {
        pole_spolecne[*t1] = *t1;
    }

    for (*t2 = 0; *t2 < 10; t2++)
    {
        pole_spolecne[*t2 + 5] = *t2;
    }

    return pole_spolecne;
}

int main()
{
    char pole1[] = { "Hello" };
    char pole2[] = { "World" };



    printf("%s\n", spojeni(pole1, pole2));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My new solution, but it returns an error at the end:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *spojeni(char *t1, char *t2)
{
    char pole_cele[20];
    char *p_pole_cele;
    p_pole_cele = t1;
    strcat(p_pole_cele, t2);

    return p_pole_cele;
}

int main()
{
    char pole1[] = { "Hello" };
    char pole2[] = { "World" };

    char *p_pole1;
    char *p_pole2;

    p_pole1 = pole1;
    p_pole2 = pole2;


    printf("%s\n)", spojeni(p_pole1, p_pole2));


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, this change of function helped:
char *spojeni(char *t1, char *t2)

```
{
    char pole_cele[20];
    char *p_pole_cele;
    p_pole_cele = (char *)malloc(10);
    strcpy(p_pole_cele, t1);
    p_pole_cele = (char *)realloc(p_pole_cele, 20);
    strcat(p_pole_cele, t2);

    return p_pole_cele;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how to answer this, as this is clearly a teaching exercise, and, to be blunt, the code given shows a lack of understanding of pointers. And pointers is a topic better taught in person than via a web-site comment.

A few hints, though:

- Think very clearly about pointers, what they are pointing to, and what makes them different from array indices.
- Draw diagrams to visualize what you're doing.
- Your exercise can be solved using calloc(), strlen() and strcpy().

Comment: Actaully, I have a new solution. It works, but after pressing a key it returns an error (see above).

Comment: Glad that it works now! Stylistically you can improve it a bit by using only a single malloc() call, and determine the size to malloc based on the length of the two input strings: malloc( strlen(t1) + strlen(t2) + 1);